# spring data - how to make unique constraint with custom logic?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

using spring data, I created **User 1:N UserDog N:1 Dog** relation. Both `1:N` relations are **unidirectional** `@ManyToOne` with `UserDog` being the custom relation table.

**User entity:**

```
@Entity
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String name;
}
```

**Dog entity:**

```
@Entity
public class Dog {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String name;
}
```

**User dog relation table:**

```
@Entity
public class UserDog {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn
    @OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
    private User user;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn
    @OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
    private Dog dog;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private Instant createdOn = Instant.now();

    @Column
    private Instant disabledOn;
}
```

**Use case**
Use case is to store history of `User`-`Dog` bindings, where the concrete `Dog` can be bound only to one `User` at the time.
 That's why I added `createdOn` and `disabledOn` columns to `UserDog`. `disabledOn` being `null` indicates that the relation is active and the `Dog` can't be assigned another `User`. If `disabledOn` is not null, then the record is stored only for evidence purposes and the `Dog` can be assigned to the same or another `User` again.

**Question**
How to ensure that the combination of **`Dog`'s id and `disabledOn` being null** is unique in `UserDog` table?
In pseudo code I want something like this:

```
@Entity
@UniqueConstraint({@UniqueConstraint(this.dog.id), @NullConstraint(this.disabledOn)})
    public class UserDog {...}
```

Comment: If this can't be done with constraint, I would like to make this work anyhow. I think that constraint would be the best, because it's simple, directly on database level; and save() operation on repository would produce exception. Are there any alternatives with transactions? Does searching for active relations in @Transactional method lock the rows so it cant be changed concurrently?

Comment: How about creating simply a unique key on `dogId` and `disabledOn`? It does the additional limitation that no two relationships may and at the same time but it seems that fits your usecase actually really nice.

Comment: Ah yes, that's reasonable. I was overthinking it. Thanks very much :) If you post this as the answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply create a unique constraint for `dogId` and `disabledOn`.

It does add the limitation that no two relationships may end at the same time but this seems to fit your use case.